# Issues running nodemon with linux

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-mint

I am running linux mint 19.2 dual boot with windows. I have a project in which I am using nodemon to restart a node server running a nextjs app. It works just fine in windows but on linux there are a couple of issues.

First when I close the terminal either the integrated terminal or vscode the nodemon process doesn't die. So when I try to restart the app after opening the terminal again or vscode there is still a process running on port 3000 so I have to kill that process to start the server again.

The next issue is when I edit and save a file the server tries to restart but then I get an error staying no such file exists. I using a file off of a mounted storage drive but I don't know why this is happening. It is very frustrating.

Here is the error I get

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
(node:3440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rmdir '/media/steveK/Storage Drive/Web Pages/React Apps/Full Stack/project/.next/cache/next-babel-loader'
(node:3440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3440) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Here is app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_DEV !== 'production';
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();
const app = express();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  app.listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`ready at http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

I have tried to use `nodemon -L app.js` but this does not help either.

Has anyone else come across issues running nodemon with linux. If so maybe you can shed some light on how I can fix the issue.

Comment: *when I close the terminal either the integrated terminal or vscode the nodemon process doesn't die* It's bad practice to leave dangling processes running when closing the terminal, unless that's specifically what you are trying to do. You should kill or close `nodemon` manually before exiting the terminal session.

Comment: Could you provide more information about your use case for `nodemon` and what's going wrong? It's hard to tell solely from a brief description of an error message what's going on.

Comment: @ifconfig I have never had to kill nodemon processes in windows that is why I am confused as to why I would have to in linux.  The processes usually die with the terminal.  Also what more information do you want?   I cannot describe the problem in any more detail.  I posted the actual error message I get for one of the issues but like I said it basically says It cannot find the file when restarting the server.

Comment: `rmdir` is a CMD terminal command. My guess is that somewhere in `app.js`, your script tries to execute a Windows terminal command in a Linux terminal.

Comment: @ifconfig no in app.js is a nodeJS and express server.  The issue is that for some reason linux is not recognizing where the directory is.

Comment: That doesn't look likely from reading the error message, but I have no way of knowing for sure without seeing the offending code. Looks to be a problem in the script to me.

Comment: @ifconfig I posted app.js there is nothing there man I am a javascript developer this is the recommend script for starting a node/express server  and server side render a nextjs app.  Also there is no errors or issues with the script without nodemon starting the server with just nodejs.  Nodemon is a development tool for starting and restarting nodejs apps when you save files in development.  The issue is with nodemon and its interaction with linux.